# Java two dimensional array only working as intended with the first row

Tags: java, arrays, minesweeper

This code is the bare-bones of a Minesweeper game board class I'm making. However, this only displays the first row of the array when I display the board. I have looked at this code for so long, and can't see where I'm going wrong with the two-dimensional array. Any help is appreciated

```
public class Board {

 private Cell[][] cells;

    public Board(PApplet p, int rows, int columns, double bombChance) {

        cells = new Cell[rows][columns];

        for (int r = 0; r < cells.length; r++) {

            for (int c = 0; c < cells[r].length; c++) {

                double randomSeed = Math.random();

                if (randomSeed < bombChance) {
                    cells[r][c] = new BombCell(p);
                } else {
                    cells[r][c] = new SafeCell(p);
                }


            }
        }

    }

    public void display() {

        double tempX = 0;
        double tempY = 0;
        double size = 50;

        for (int r = 0; r < cells.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cells[r].length; c++) {

                cells[r][c].display(tempX, tempY, size);

                tempX += 50;
            }

            tempY += 50;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to separate game logic from presentation logic. Things will get a lot easier

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I have a separate Minesweeper class to deal with game logic and modify the board. However, the array of cells itself is dealt with here, so this is where the problem would be found.

Comment: How does yor Cell.display Method looks like?

Comment: Step through the code.  And what is the value of `rows` and `columns`?

Comment: Breakpoints go a long way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are failing to reset `tempX` when you start to render the next row.

This may fix your issue:

```
public void display() {

    double tempX = 0;
    double tempY = 0;
    double size = 50;

    for (int r = 0; r < cells.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < cells[r].length; c++) {

            cells[r][c].display(tempX, tempY, size);

            tempX += 50;
        }

        tempY += 50;
        tempX = 0;           // <-------------- look here

    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help @JoshKatofsky

Comment: @jlordo You are correct. However once a row is rendered, tempX needs to be reset to 0. The original code did not reset tempX to 0 at the end of the row.

Comment: you can even improve by getting rid of `tempX` and `tempY` by using `(r * size)` and `(c * size)`

Comment: @ThomasPawlitzki thank you for this as well, another set of eyes can really streamline your code!

Comment: @mangotang gave you one, Stackoverflow said it's not going to be displayed because I'm a newbie to their site though :(